# How to disable ASP.NET Core Caching (FusionCache) for the test scenarios?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, fusion-cache

I'm using [Fusion Cache](https://github.com/ZiggyCreatures/FusionCache) in ASP.NET Core (v6.0) project.
I need to turn off the cache (globally) for some environments (in this case, tests).
*I'm looking for the best practices.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FusionCache creator here.

Your approach definitely works and is reasonable, but what I'm thinking about is if it would make sense to have a ready-made *"null/no-op implementation"* of `IFusionCache` directly, something that works as a simple pass-through like you did.

For your scenario it would mean not having to introduce a new `ICacheService` abstraction, and keep depending on `IFusionCache` without having to change the existing code.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE (2023-07-09)**

I've decided to officially add support for a `NullFusionCache` (just like the `NullLogger` in .NET itself), and I created an [issue](https://github.com/ZiggyCreatures/FusionCache/issues/151) to track the development.

Btw, the development is already done, and tests have been created to make sure everything is fine.

Will release [v0.22.0](https://github.com/ZiggyCreatures/FusionCache/milestone/4) in the next days, let me know what you think.

Thanks!

**UPDATE (2023-07-10)**

Hi! I just released [v0.22.0](https://github.com/ZiggyCreatures/FusionCache/releases/tag/v0.22.0) and the `NullFusionCache` class is now included

Comment: happy u r here.   
The first thing that crossed my mind was implementing `NoOpFusionCache : IFusionCache`.    
And Guess what, I've stuck here.
```csharp
public ValueTask<TValue?> GetOrSetAsync<TValue>(...)
    {
        return factory.Invoke(new FusionCacheFactoryExecutionContext<TValue>(key, options, failSafeDefaultValue, token), token);
    }
``` 
The Ctor of `FusionCacheFactoryExecutionContext<TValue>` is internal!

Comment: Eheh, same suggestion I was about to give you 

But then I realized that you would then need to keep track of new features (new methods to implements, etc) when that should be directly FusionCache concern, for something so generic.

Comment: I am about to release a new version, I may include this directly since the implementation looks like to be dead simple (I may have to think a bit about possible misuses or pitfalls, but still).

Comment: Ah, you are right! The idea is that the construction of a factory execution context is an internal detail, and I can make changes to that without breaking existing code.
Let me think about it, will update you.

Answer (score 0):

**I came up with some scenarios and I'll explain the solution I found most impressive.**

I've created my own `ICacheService` interface with the methods I needed and have two implementations: one using *FusionCache* and the other one bypassing the cache.
The choice between these two implementations would be made in the `Startup` class.

> Considering that I used to inject `IFusionCache` into all caching services, I have to replace them with `ICacheService`.

1. Have a setting in `appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "Caching": {
    "Enabled": true
  }
  // other settings...
}
```

2. Create class and map configuration:

```cs
public class CacheConfig
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

3. The interface:

```cs
public interface ICacheService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the value of type <typeparamref name="TValue"/> in the cache for the specified <paramref name="key"/>: if not there, the <paramref name="factory"/> will be called and the returned value saved.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value in the cache.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The cache key which identifies the entry in the cache.</param>
    /// <param name="factory">The function which will be called if the value is not found in the cache.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">An optional <see cref="CancellationToken"/> to cancel the operation.</param>
    /// <returns>The value in the cache, either already there or generated using the provided <paramref name="factory"/> .</returns>
    public ValueTask<TValue?> GetOrSetAsync<TValue>(string key,
        Func<CancellationToken, Task<TValue?>> factory,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

}
```

4. The implementation based on *FusionCache*:

```
public class FusionCacheService : ICacheService
{
    private readonly IFusionCache _cache;

    public FusionCacheService(IFusionCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public ValueTask<TValue?> GetOrSetAsync<TValue>(string key,
        Func<CancellationToken, Task<TValue?>> factory,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => _cache.GetOrSetAsync<TValue>(key, (_, ct) => factory(ct), default, null, cancellationToken);
}
```

5. The implementation with no-cache:

```cs
public class NoOpCacheService : ICacheService
{
    public async ValueTask<TValue?> GetOrSetAsync<TValue>(string key,
        Func<CancellationToken, Task<TValue?>> factory,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
        await factory(cancellationToken);
}
```

6. And the wire-up at the `Startup`:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddCache(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
    IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var cacheSettings = new CacheConfig();
    configuration.Bind(CacheConfig.SectionName, cacheSettings);

    if (!cacheSettings.Enabled)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICacheService, NoOpCacheService>();
        return serviceCollection;
    }

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICacheService, FusionCacheService>();
    serviceCollection.AddMemoryCache();
    serviceCollection.AddFusionCache()
        .WithOptions(options =>
        {
.
.
.
```

With this approach, I have more **control** over the **behavior** of the service as well as **Decoupling**, **Reduced dependency**, and **Ease of testing**.